# get url from previous ViewController then download the content from the url

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to download the image from a url and the url is from the previous ViewController.Here is what I have done:

```
import UIKit

class quotesContentsViewController: UIViewController {

    var feed: quotesContentFeed?

    var urlSession: NSURLSession!

    weak var dataTask: NSURLSessionDataTask?

    var quotesContentURLString: String?

    @IBOutlet var quotes: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var author: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet var backgroundImage: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {

        //let request = NSURLRequest(URL: self.imageURL!)



        super.viewDidLoad()

        if let quotesContentURL = NSURL(string: quotesContentURLString!) {
            self.updateQuotesContentFeed(quotesContentURL, completion: {(feed) -> Void in
                //print(feed!.item.imageURL)*
                self.feed = feed!
                self.author.text = feed!.item.author
                self.quotes.text = feed!.item.quotes

                let imageURLString = self.feed!.item.imageURL
                let imageURL = NSURL(string: imageURLString)
                let request = NSURLRequest(URL: imageURL!)
                    //OK
                self.dataTask = self.urlSession.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {(data, response, error) -> Void in

                        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock({ () -> Void in
                            if error == nil && data != nil {
                                print(imageURL)
                                let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                                self.backgroundImage.image = image
                            }
                        })
                    }


            })
        }
        //print(self.feed!.item.imageURL)


        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

`quotesContentURLString` is what I got from the previous ViewController. `updateQuotesContentFeed` take the `quotesContentURL` .`feed` is a struct containing three String properties,author,quotes and imageURL.

Now I want to download the content from `imageURL`, but what I have done is not working properly. It seems like `self.dataTask = self.urlSession.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {(data, response, error) -> Void in` will never be executed.

So how to solve the problem?

Comment: Are you setting the value for `quotesContentURLString` in your `prepareForSegue` method in your first view controller?

Comment: @ZacharyGover Yes,I did.

Comment: Is the url being served over HTTPS?

Comment: Finally done! I missed the `self.datatask?.resume()`,So the dataTask will never be executed.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!